# How do I share memory from main program with a thread in linux

Tags: c, linux, memory, pthreads, share

I've edited my question. It appears that threads operate differently from what I expected (windows vs linux). Here is the complete working example:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void *testing(void *mptr)
{
char *mystr;
mystr=(char *)mptr;
printf(mystr);
printf("finished running thread\n");
return NULL;
}

int main()
{
pthread_t mythread;
char *str1;

str1=malloc(50);
strcpy(str1,"Hello World\n");
printf(str1);
printf("About to start\n");

//pthread_create(&mythread, NULL, testing, str1);

printf("finished creating thread\n");
printf(str1);
free(str1);
return 0;
}
```

Above program produces:

```
Hello world
About to start
finished creating thread
Hello World
```

Please note that I am not creating a thread in it - the specific line is commented out.
How ever if I don't comment out the "pthread_create.." -line the output is sporadic, sometimes has garbage:

```
Hello world
About to start
finished creating thread
Hello World
&%¤&finished creating thread
```

Sometimes the garbled part is ok, sometimes it show as "o World" etc.

From What I've googled is that stack is not shared the same way that Windows does this.

How can I access memory that I malloc'd in the main program later in the thread? Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you show us where and how you are defining `somelinkedlist`?

Comment: Voting to close. [See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I agree with DevNull, the code you've shown is not the code that has the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should wait for the thread to finish before freeing the string?

pthread_join is your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

I got my problem figured out. It was probably memory getting clobbered.
However those who read my initial question did not like me not posting a full source and I got -3 downvotes.

I then edited the my original question to provide a complete test source.

Unfortunately those who initially downvoted me haven't checked back if I've fixed my question.

Now the downvotes have banned me from entering new questions on Stackoverflow. I have now total -6 downvotes from two "bad" questions.
So please: those who downvoted: please lift the downvotes.